# Miniconda - "conda" command does not work

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, conda, data-analysis, miniconda

I have installed Miniconda (Miniconda-3.16.0-Linux-armv7l) on my Raspbian-runned Raspberry Pi 3, but I have failed to install packages.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ conda install jupyter
bash: /home/pi/miniconda/bin/conda: /home/pi/miniconda/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you do the install?

Comment: Your problem may be similar to this previous question: [conda command will prompt error: “Bad Interpreter: No such file or directory”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39884499/conda-command-will-prompt-error-bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory#39884767)