# Unable to use Theano Keras backend inside Google Cloud DL VM

Tags: python, keras, theano, google-dl-platform

I'm trying to run Keras on a Google Cloud Deep Learning VM instance using the Theano backend instead of the default Tensorflow one. I can ssh into the instance as the `jupyter` user and subsequently run `pip install theano`, just trying to import theano from the python prompt also works, but when I set the Keras backend to Theano in Jupyter Lab (via `os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND'] = 'theano'`), anytime I try to train a model I receive this strange error message:

```
ERROR (theano.gof.cmodule): [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/anaconda1anaconda2anaconda3/lib'
```

What's up with that?

Answer (score 1):

Something must have gone wrong during the installation, I suppose. The bad interpreter means that a script is looking for an interpreter that doesn't exist - as you rightfully pointed out.

The problem is likely to be in the shebang #! statement of your conda script.

From Wikipedia: Under Unix-like operating systems, when a script with a shebang is run as a program, the program loader parses the rest of the script's initial line as an interpreter directive; the specified interpreter program is run instead, passing to it as an argument the path that was initially used when attempting to run the script.

If you run

cat ~/anaconda3/bin/conda
You will probably get the following:

## !/opt/anaconda1anaconda2anaconda3/bin/python

if **name** == '**main**':
    import sys
    import conda.cli

```
sys.exit(conda.cli.main())
```

Changing the first line to point a correct interpreter, i.e., changing it to:

## !/home/lukasz/anaconda3/bin/python

Should make the conda command work.

If you are sure that you installed everything properly, then I'd suggest maybe reaching out for support from the anaconda community.

Answered by @dangom in [conda command will prompt error: "Bad Interpreter: No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39884499/conda-command-will-prompt-error-bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Anaconda is not installed on that system (I should probably have mentioned that), I installed theano via `pip install theano`, that's what makes this so weird to me.

Comment: If you run the following code, what does it say?
import sys
print(sys.executable)

Comment: I already tried that, it's `/usr/bin/python3`, the system comes pre-configured but I'm certain there are no virtual python environments of any type set up.

Comment: I assume that you have tried a reinstall (of theano)? There are no python2 on the machine?