# Error while loading conda.... please give few ideas

Tags: python, anaconda, load, conda

Just installed Anaconda 3 yesterday. The install went fine. Didn't see any errors.
Trying to load,  I was told this is the way to load it.

```
-bash-4.2$ module load anaconda/conda3
-bash-4.2$ conda create --name xyz python=3.7
-bash: /nfs/apps/anaconda/anaconda3/bin/conda: /qumulo/systems/hot/opt/x86_64/centos7/anaconda/anaconda3/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

when I install, I install everything under /qumulo....   but when the users sees it, they will see it as  /nfs/apps/anaconda/anaconda3....

I did update the etc/profile.d/conda.sh

anything else, I am missing.   Any ideas.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [conda command will prompt error: "Bad Interpreter: No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39884499/conda-command-will-prompt-error-bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory)